# Selenium: Record test steps + Exception in Extent Report

Tags: selenium, extentreports

I have develop automation testing using selenium, extent report. I wonder how to record test steps for a particular test and report it in Extent Report. I have exception recorded but lack of test steps.

Please provide an overview on how to implement this.

EDIT:
Sorry let me rephrase my questions: How to pass Java Exception to Extent Listener using TestNG. The result.getThrowable() is not same as exception throw in eclipse console.

Comment: if you want to record steps , it will be better to use allure

Comment: Do you have any concrete supporting information to support your opinion?

Comment: Are you using BDD such as Cucumber or JBehave?  Extent Reports interfaces directly with Cucumber and it's not too difficult to implement with JBehave.  Everything you need to know to use Extent Reports, including BDD implementation, is well-documented on their web site.

Comment: Are you hosting your reports over a web server? If yes, you can link to your recordings and view them. Otherwise, it is not possible to do so..

Comment: Does extent report server have this capabilities?

Comment: http://allure.qatools.ru/, you go through it , i believe you will definitely get the solution

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my questions: How to pass Java Exception to Extent Listener using TestNG. The result.getThrowable() is not same as exception throw in eclipse console.

Comment: @peterwkc You may refer this answer, if it fits to as you required.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368190/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-complete-error-exception-using-itestresult-in-the-afte/52379386#52379386