# ITestResult returns status Success even if a method in testng class is throwing an exception

Tags: testng

I have added a testListener class and with my test code but even if the calling method in the testNG class gets an exception, the `ITestResult` status shows Success and goes to `onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr)` method.

**testNG class**

```
    @Test  (invocationCount=1)
    public void offersPageRefresh() 
    {
       //Some steps
       cart.selectAndVerifyOffersBanner();
    }
```

**Cart page class**

```
public void selectAndVerifyOffersBanner()
{
    try {
            //Some steps.
            moveToElement(selectOffersButton_MobileSite,driver);
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Offers banner selected and verified successfully.");
            } catch (WebDriverException | InterruptedException e) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Offers banner selection and verification Failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now, if `selectOffersButton_MobileSite` element is not present it throws the `NoSuchElementException` and enters into the catch block and the logger prints the failure message properly. But on completion of `offersPageRefresh()` ITestResult returns status Success and goes to `onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr)` and shows test status as Passed.

What changes are required in order to fix this particular situation. Please suggest and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `selectAndVerifyOffersBanner()` you handle the exception by using the `try/catch` So there is no exception now and you test shows as pass.

In `catch` once you done with logging, throw the same exception which you handle like

```
 throw e;
```

or

```
throw new Exception(e.getMessage()); //it create a new Exception object and throw it
```

Then test will fails.

Comment: murali selenium, Thanks for the help. I have changed the catch block accordingly.

Comment: You can just do `throw e;` (throwing the same exception object) instead of creating a new `Exception` object and throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

`ITestResult` gives result of `@Test` based on how it is handled.

If `@Test` has been already handle by `try/catch` block, It means we are allowing to continue our test execution. And if exception throws it is handle by `catch` block. So here `@Test` failure is not picturized due to `try/catch` handling.

If you want to trace your exception through `ITestResult` then you need to avoid `try/catch` handling.

[Reference example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379386/9405154)